# AJAX: Sync or queue?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am working on some Webservices with AJAX calls.
On my webpage, the user has to select one or more people to join a group.This 'group list' is sent to a PHP page (using POST method) which will execute the associated WebServices.

My problem is about sync/async AJAX calls.
I aim to show an animation (a gif for example) during the process, which blocks the user interface, and at the end show the message "Complete". I use two Jquery plugins: Apprise for the message and jquery msg for the animation.

In sync mode: the animation is not displayed, but when the AJAX calls are finished, the message "Complete" is displayed.
In async mode: the animation is displayed, but the message "complete" is displayed before the end of the AJAX calls.

So my question is, do I have to queue multiple asynchronous AJAX calls ? Or anything else ?

Comment: You are getting complete early because you aren't waiting for the request to be complete to display complete. ***Use callbacks!***

Comment: @ThmMrn did my answer help you? If not please tell us what is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this may be caused because you have multiple async calls running at the same moment.

I use the following small script to control how many ajax calls are currently running:

```
$.xhrPool = { calls: [] };
$.xhrPool.abortAll = function () {
    $(this.calls).each(function (idx, jqXHR) {
        jqXHR.abort();
    });
    $.xhrPool.calls = [];
};


// Setup ajax requests
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (jqXHR) {
        $.xhrPool.calls.push(jqXHR);
    },
    complete: function (jqXHR) {
        var isInArray = $.inArray(jqXHR, $.xhrPool.calls);

        if (isInArray > -1) {
            $.xhrPool.calls.splice(isInArray, 1);
        }
    }
});
```

This way you will have all currently active ajax request in the array `$.xhrPool.calls`. You could then check `if ($.xhrPool.calls.length == 0)` and if yes remove your loading animation.

Furthermore you can call `$.xhrPool.abortAll()` which will stop all active ajax requests.

Comment: I believe it would be sufficient to track the _count_ of pending AJAX calls. Do you have a reason to store all of them in a list?